# How to force one ChartArea on each row with Microsoft Chart control

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, charts, data-visualization

I am using the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart control to draw some charts. 
I can have between 2 and 5 ChartArea, with several Series in each ChartArea.

My problem is when I have 4 ChartArea or more, whatever the total height of my control is, the control attempts to generate two charts area on the same row. 
When I have only 3 ChartArea, the render is fine.

**I would like to know how I could enforce this behavior to have all chart area one under the others.**

Here's a completely working LINQPAD example (just paste it in LINQPad and add references for System.Drawing and System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting. To toggle the number of ChartArea just change the nbSources constant) :

```
// Chart generation code (the interesting part!) :
void Main()
{
    TestDataLight testData = new TestDataLight();
    var drivesData = testData.BuildData();
    ChartManagerLight chartMgr = new ChartManagerLight();
    chartMgr.CreateChart(drivesData);
    var chart = chartMgr.GetResultAsImage();

    Util.Image(chart).Dump();
}

public class ChartManagerLight
{
    private Chart _chartSmart;

    private static readonly Font TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Bold);
    private static readonly Font LegendFont = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular);

    public void CreateChart(List<SourceData> sourcesData)
    {
        _chartSmart = new Chart();

        _chartSmart.Width = 950;
        _chartSmart.Height = sourcesData.Count * 300; // I except one chartarea on each "line", with 300px for each

        _chartSmart.IsMapEnabled = true;
        _chartSmart.MapAreas.Add(new MapArea() { Name = "chartSMART" });

        StyleChart();

        for (int iSource = 0; iSource < sourcesData.Count; iSource++)
        {
            var source = sourcesData[iSource];

            CreateChartArea(source, iSource);
        }
    }

    private void CreateChartArea(SourceData source, int iSource)
    {
        string chartAreaName = source.SourceName;

        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
        chartArea.Name = chartAreaName;
        _chartSmart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

        Title tt = new Title();
        tt.Name = "Title" + iSource;
        tt.Text = source.SourceName;
        tt.DockedToChartArea = chartArea.Name;
        tt.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
        tt.Font = TitleFont;
        _chartSmart.Titles.Add(tt);

        foreach (var indicatorX in source.GetAllIndicators())
        {
            CreateSerie(source, indicatorX, chartAreaName);
        }
    }

    private void CreateSerie(SourceData source, IndicatorXType indicatorX, string chartAreaName)
    {
        var seriePoints = source.Reports.Select(r => new Tuple<DateTime, int>(r.Date, r.GetIndicator(indicatorX).Value)).ToList();
        var serieName = chartAreaName + indicatorX.Description;

        Series serie = new Series();
        serie.Name = serieName;
        _chartSmart.Series.Add(serie);

        serie.ChartArea = chartAreaName;
        serie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        serie.Points.DataBind(seriePoints, "Item1", "Item2", string.Empty);

        serie.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        serie.Font = LegendFont;
    }

    private void StyleChart()
    {
        _chartSmart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(211, 223, 240);
        _chartSmart.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        _chartSmart.BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;
        _chartSmart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
        _chartSmart.BorderlineWidth = 1;
        _chartSmart.BorderlineColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
        _chartSmart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
        _chartSmart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
        _chartSmart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High;
    }

    public byte[] GetResultAsImage()
    {
        _chartSmart.RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        _chartSmart.SaveImage(ms);

        return ms.GetBuffer();
    }
}

// Dummy data structure and generation (only needed to make the example to work) :

public class TestDataLight
{
    const int nbSources = 4;
    const int nbReportXsPerSource = 9;
    const int nbDaysBetweenEachReportX = 3;
    const int nbIndicatorXs = 5;

    public List<SourceData> BuildData()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        List<SourceData> sourceDatas = new List<SourceData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nbSources; i++)
        {
            SourceData source = new SourceData();
            source.SourceName = "Source " + i;
            var testData = new List<SourceReport>();
            source.Reports = testData;

            for (int iXData = -(nbReportXsPerSource * nbDaysBetweenEachReportX); iXData < 0; iXData += nbDaysBetweenEachReportX)
            {
                var reportX = new SourceReport() { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(iXData), SourceName = "Source 1" };

                for (int iIndicatorX = 0; iIndicatorX < nbIndicatorXs; iIndicatorX++)
                {
                    var indicatorXType = new IndicatorXType() { Id = iIndicatorX, Description = "IndicatorX " + (char)(('A') + iIndicatorX) + " (" + iIndicatorX + ")"};
                    reportX.Values.Add(new IndicatorValue(indicatorXType, rnd.Next(0, 100)));
                }

                testData.Add(reportX);
            }

            sourceDatas.Add(source);
        }

        return sourceDatas;
    }
}

public class SourceData
{
    public string SourceName { get; set; }

    public List<SourceReport> Reports { get; set; }

    public List<IndicatorXType> GetAllIndicators()
    {
        return Reports.SelectMany(r => r.Values.Select(v => v.Type)).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}

public class SourceReport
{
    public string SourceName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<IndicatorValue> Values { get; set; }

    public SourceReport()
    {
        Values = new List<IndicatorValue>();
    }

    public IndicatorValue GetIndicator(IndicatorXType indicatorX)
    {
        return Values.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Type.Description == indicatorX.Description);
    }
}

public class IndicatorValue
{
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Object" /> class.</summary>
    public IndicatorValue(IndicatorXType type, int value)
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
    }

    public IndicatorXType Type { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public struct IndicatorXType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

With 3 charts (ok) :
[image: With 3 charts (ok)]

With 4 charts or more (what I want to change to always have the same render as in 3 charts version) :
[image: With 4 charts or more (what I want to change)]

Thanks !

Comment: Please see if [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37567878/align-chartareas-in-chart-control-horizontally/37569501#37569501) helps.

Comment: @jstreet Thanks. I had already tried a such like solution but it was giving weird results. Maybe I didn't properly initialized all properties, or I was confused by the percentile. Anyway, I reworked it base on your link and it was ok. I will post the complete solution.

Comment: You're very welcome. Remember to mark your own answer as accepted and remember to up vote posts that were helpful to you...:O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jstreet answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37569501/461444), I have been able to make it work. I share the solution, hope it can be helpful for somebody else :).

Just complete the "CreateChartArea" method with this after to have created chartArea object :

```
private void CreateChartArea(SourceData source, int iSource, int sourceCount)
{
    string chartAreaName = source.SourceName;

    ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
    chartArea.Name = chartAreaName;
    chartArea.Position.Auto = false;
    chartArea.Position.X = 1;
    chartArea.Position.Y = 2f + (iSource / (float)sourceCount) * 98f;
    chartArea.Position.Height = (97f / sourceCount);
    chartArea.Position.Width = 96f; 

    ...
}
```

All values are in percentage. 
"sourceCount" is equal to sourcesData.Count.
I have manage some margin before/after, especially because the "Title" other each ChartArea seems to not be a part of the ChartArea itself. Also, width must not be 100% or it will go out of the drawing area as far as I can see.

It works for me with different counts of ChartArea. However, if there is a magic property to adjust all this in a cleaner way, automatically for example, I would be happy to know about it.